# For "large" data, is it better to use sql connection or import a csv file

Tags: sql-server, r, csv

So I'm trying to connect to a database using dplyr and execute commands on that data. However, the process if taking far too long (> 10 minutes). In SQL Server, it takes around 2 minutes, so I could just export it as a csv and then import it into R or Python. So as a general rule, do you suggest using sql connections from R or Python, or exporting a csv file directly from the sql database.

Here's the R code I'm using:

```
library(dplyr)
aw <- RSQLServer::src_sqlserver("****", database = "****")

dept <- tbl(aw, sql("select work_dt, campaign, keyword, 
                     impressions, clicks, cost
                     from abidwise_detail
                     where work_dt between '2014-01-01' and '2014-05-01'")))

(dept <- tbl(aw, sql("select work_dt, campaign, keyword, 
                     sum(impressions) as impressions,
                     sum(clicks) as clicks,
                     sum(cost) as cost
                     from abidwise_detail
                     where work_dt between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01'
                     group by work_dt, campaign, keyword")))

rd <- dept %>% 
  filter(campaign == "ask")

# Bring the full data set back to R
dat <- collect(rd)
```

What should I do. both of these queries take too long. Should I just export as a csv file and just read the files in from a directory.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should do whatever best suits your specific circumstances. If you don't mind manually exporting CSV data from SQL Server, and it is faster than the other alternatives, then do that.

Comment: maybe the `data.table` package might be interesting for you in this case

Comment: @Deena is right, try `data.table::fread()`, it's the fastest (and easiest) way to import large delimited files.